# How to change color of a cell of table in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table of items.  How do I make a cell turn color, lets say to red if the item is equal to 0

[image: You can see the fridge is 0 as quantity]

The ID of the table is myTable. I don't know how I should do this in javascript. I have added an id:

```
<td id="quantity"><?php echo e(($row['Quantity'])); ?></td>
  function ChangeColor(){
  .... //what goes here
}
```

Comment: Do you running with laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to do this in PHP at run time, not in JavaScript like you hint at:

For example,

```
 <?php 
   $backgroundColor = $row['Quantity'] == 0 ? 'red' : 'none';
   echo '<td id="quantity" style="background-color: ' . $backgroundColor .'">' . e(($row['Quantity'])) . '</td>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` instead of `id`

```html
<td class="quantity"><?php echo e(($row['Quantity'])); ?></td>
```

then select the `<td>` that has the "quantity" class, and evaluate their content

```js
document.querySelectorAll('td.quantity').forEach(e => {
  if( Number(e.textContent) < 0)
    e.classList.add('negativeQtty')
})
```

then declare a css class `negativeQtty`

```css
.negativeQtty {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain further why to `trim()`?

Comment: indeed, `.trim()` might not be necessary when using `Number()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap background class

```
<td id="quantity"class="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white"><?php echo e(($row['Quantity'])); ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a code `javascript` if you want use a `javascript`.
Need a call with `cell` of `th` then give a `cell.innerHTML`.

**This example**

```js
var th = document.querySelectorAll('th')
for (let cell of th) {
  if(cell.innerHTML === '6'){
    cell.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
  }
  if(cell.innerHTML === '0'){
    cell.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: .25em .5em;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  font: .75em "Verdana";
}
```

```html
<table id="Table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Data</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Product2</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>0</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```